# Keypad with a Arduino Nano

Tags: python, arduino

I've been trying to make a keypad using a Arduino Nano. I know that the Nano cannot use the <keyboard.h library>. I have all the basics down but I'm still having one issue. When ever I press a key too fast, the inputs stack on each other and I hit some sort of tying limit with Pyautogui. Here is the python script.

```
import serial
import keyboard
import time
import pydirectinput
import pyautogui

ser = serial.Serial('COM4', baudrate=9600)
time.sleep(2)
ser.flushInput()
while True:
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    print(ser_bytes)
    if (ser_bytes == b'w\r\n'):
           print("Press")
           pydirectinput.keyDown('w')
           pydirectinput.keyUp('w')
```

The limit seems to be around "keyDown" "keyUp" command per second. Using the Arduino serial monitor and plotter, the signal is working fine, so something is wrong with the python script.

Thank you

Comment: please add more information regarding the error you are seeing

Comment: Apologies. The error is that pyautogui is not typing very fast.